# Get Phone or Email with API4 not possible?

Tags: contacts, email, apiv4, phone, missing

I played around with the ApiExplorer for API4
While the doc says default select would be * it doesn't return all contact details.
So I added the SELECT for phone_primary and email_primary and joined the phoneDB.
This worked for one phonenumber, but all the other phonenumber which can be set for a
contact (e.g. fax,mobile) don't show up.

Anyway, I tried to use the curl example from the ApiExplorer and it worked so far it returns all contacts and a lot senseless details.
However, limit the request is not working at all. It always returns all contacts.
Also phone and email are always missing no matter what I do.

My Postman request looks like this:

> https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/civicrm/ajax/api4/Contact/get?select=
> ["email_primary.*", "phone.*", "first_name", "last_name",
> "phone.mobile_provider_id", "organization_name"]&join= [["Phone AS
> phone", "LEFT"]]&limit=5
>
> This are my params in Postman: {"select": ["email_primary.*",
> "phone.*", "first_name", "last_name", "phone.mobile_provider_id",
> "organization_name"],   "join": [["Phone AS phone", "LEFT"]],
> "limit": 5}

This is what API-Explorer shows as valid curl example. But it's not working as curl or Postman request.
As mentioned a lot senseless contact details are returned but phone and email are always missing in the result.

> CRM_URL='https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/civicrm/ajax/api4/Contact/get' CRM_AUTH='X-Civi-Auth: Bearer MY_API_KEY'
>
> curl -X POST -H "$CRM_AUTH" "$CRM_URL" 
> -d 'params=%7B%22select%22%3A%5B%22email_primary.%2a%22%2C%22phone.%2a%22%2C%22first_name%22%2C%22last_name%22%2C%22phone.mobile_provider_id%22%2C%22organization_name%22%5D%2C%22join%22%3A%5B%5B%22Phone%20AS%20phone%22%2C%22LEFT%22%5D%5D%2C%22limit%22%3A5%7D'

While emails and phonenumber are returned in the ApiExplorer for API3 with a similar request, the curl example for API3 is not working at all. (Invalid url)

I don't get it where the problem is.
Are this ApiExplorer examples still up to date?
Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like there are 2 parts to your question. StackExchange is set up to answer one question at a time, so it might have been better to ask one question about how to fetch all contact Emails and another about how to properly encode curl requests.

Comment: Well, actually I just added all details I gathered while trying to make it work.
Yes, the problem is just to get email and phone numbers when fetching a contacts 
I don't know If it's a problem of curl format, wrong examples or an api4 bug. Maybe the api3 api4 inconsistence behavior is another way to narrow down the problem?!?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a 2-parter so I'll just answer your first question about how to fetch all emails & phones for a contact. Please start a new post for your curl question.

APIv4 *does* fetch all fields (aka `SELECT *`) by default, but only fields that actually belong to the entity. If you inspect the `civicrm_contact` table in SQL you'll see that `email` is not actually a column. Rather it's a join to another table.

APIv4 can do a lot of fancy stuff with joins, but you have to ask it to (if it did *all* the fancy stuff by default it would probably blow up your server or at least significantly slow it down).

It's all a bit too much to explain in one StackExchange answer, so I recommend you go and check out the docs on:

1. [Implicit Joins](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/implicit-joins/)
2. [Explicit Joins](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/explicit-joins/)

And in addition to the API Explorer, try playing with SearchKit. It's a bit more user-friendly and can generate the types of aggregate joins you wanted (e.g. fetching multiple emails per contact) with just a few clicks. Then click on the "Query Info" tab and SearchKit will show you the APIv4 params it has generated to do all the fancy stuff you asked for.